# Angularjs - fullcalendar switching between month view and week view not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, fullcalendar, angularjs-1.6, ui-calendar

I'm using angular js & angular-UI/UI-calendar. **I want to load events from the rest API when the view is changed (month, week, etc.)** In the next/previous button, on page load, everything works fine.Also works changeView function on view switch but data not set.

Refer this Link - https://angular-ui.github.io/ui-calendar/

I am stuck,Please help me out with what's going wrong.

Here My code,

```
$scope.eventsF = function (start, end, timezone, callback) {
    console.log('eventsF');
    var obj = angular.copy($scope.filter);
    var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar('getCalendar');
    var view = calendar.view;
    if (!view) {
        $scope.setFlash('e', "Something Wrong In getting Data.Please Refresh Again");
        return false;
    }
    console.log(view);
    obj.view_name = view.name;
    obj.start_date = moment(view.intervalStart._d).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
    obj.end_date = moment(view.intervalEnd._d).subtract(1, "days").format("YYYY-MM-DD");
    if (view.name == "agendaWeek") {
        weekly_calenderService.get_calender_week_wise_visits(obj).then(function (res) {
            $scope.mainEvents = [];
            if (res.data.flag) {
                $scope.pendingEvents = [];
                $scope.completeEvents = [];
                $scope.missEvents = [];
                $scope.savedEvents = [];
                var calEvents = [];
                _.each(res.data.data, function (nw) {
                    if (nw.status == 0) {
                        var date = nw.target_date.split('-');
                        var in_time = nw.target_intime.split(':');
                        var out_time = nw.target_outtime.split(':');
                    } else {
                        var date = nw.visit_date.split('-');
                        var in_time = nw.visit_intime.split(':');
                        var out_time = nw.visit_outtime.split(':');
                    }
                    if (nw.status == 0) {
                        $scope.pendingEvents.push({
                            title: nw.patient.first + ' ' + nw.patient.last,
                            event_info: nw,
                            start: new Date(date[0], (date[1] * 1) - 1, date[2], in_time[0], in_time[1]),
                            end: new Date(date[0], (date[1] * 1) - 1, date[2], out_time[0], out_time[1]),
                            className: 'calender-week-badge bg-primary',
                            allDay: false,
                            status: 0,
                            view: obj.view_name
                        });
                    }
                    if (nw.status == 1 || nw.status == 3 || nw.status == 4) {
                        $scope.completeEvents.push({
                            title: nw.patient.first + ' ' + nw.patient.last,
                            event_info: nw,
                            start: new Date(date[0], (date[1] * 1) - 1, date[2], in_time[0], in_time[1]),
                            end: new Date(date[0], (date[1] * 1) - 1, date[2], out_time[0], out_time[1]),
                            className: 'calender-week-badge bg-success',
                            allDay: false,
                            status: 1,
                            view: obj.view_name
                        });
                    }
                    if (nw.status == 2) {
                        $scope.missEvents.push({
                            title: nw.patient.first + ' ' + nw.patient.last,
                            event_info: nw,
                            start: new Date(date[0], (date[1] * 1) - 1, date[2], in_time[0], in_time[1]),
                            end: new Date(date[0], (date[1] * 1) - 1, date[2], out_time[0], out_time[1]),
                            className: 'calender-week-badge bg-danger',
                            allDay: false,
                            status: 2,
                            view: obj.view_name
                        });
                    }
                    if (nw.status == 5) {
                        $scope.savedEvents.push({
                            title: nw.patient.first + ' ' + nw.patient.last,
                            event_info: nw,
                            start: new Date(date[0], (date[1] * 1) - 1, date[2], in_time[0], in_time[1]),
                            end: new Date(date[0], (date[1] * 1) - 1, date[2], out_time[0], out_time[1]),
                            className: 'calender-week-badge bg-warning',
                            allDay: false,
                            status: 5,
                            view: obj.view_name
                        });
                    }
                })
                $scope.mainEvents = $scope.pendingEvents.concat($scope.completeEvents, $scope.missEvents, $scope.savedEvents);
                callback($scope.mainEvents);
            } else {
                $scope.datewise_event_data = [];
                $scope.mainEvents = [];
                $scope.eventInfoStatus = -1;
                $scope.setFlash('e', res.data.message);
            }
        })
    } else {
        weekly_calenderService.get_calender_month_wise_visits(obj).then(function (res) {
            if (res.data.flag) {
                $scope.mainEvents = [];
                $scope.pendingEvents = [];
                $scope.completeEvents = [];
                $scope.missEvents = [];
                $scope.savedEvents = [];
                _.each(res.data.data, function (nw) {
                    var date = nw.date.split('-');
                    if (nw.pending > 0) {
                        $scope.pendingEvents.push({
                            title: nw.pending,
                            event_info: nw,
                            start: new Date((date[0] * 1), (date[1] * 1) - 1, (date[2] * 1)),
                            className: 'calender-month-badge bg-primary',
                            allDay: false,
                            status: 0,
                            date: nw.date,
                            view: obj.view_name
                        });
                    }
                    if (nw.complete > 0) {
                        $scope.completeEvents.push({
                            title: nw.complete,
                            event_info: nw,
                            start: new Date((date[0] * 1), (date[1] * 1) - 1, (date[2] * 1), 0, 0),
                            className: 'calender-month-badge bg-success',
                            allDay: false,
                            status: 1,
                            date: nw.date,
                            view: obj.view_name
                        });
                    }
                    if (nw.missed > 0) {
                        $scope.missEvents.push({
                            title: nw.missed,
                            event_info: nw,
                            start: new Date((date[0] * 1), (date[1] * 1) - 1, (date[2] * 1)),
                            className: 'calender-month-badge bg-danger',
                            allDay: false,
                            status: 2,
                            date: nw.date,
                            view: obj.view_name
                        });
                    }
                    if (nw.saved > 0) {
                        $scope.savedEvents.push({
                            title: nw.saved,
                            event_info: nw,
                            start: new Date((date[0] * 1), (date[1] * 1) - 1, (date[2] * 1)),
                            className: 'calender-month-badge bg-warning',
                            allDay: false,
                            status: 5,
                            date: nw.date,
                            view: obj.view_name
                        });
                    }
                })
                $scope.mainEvents = $scope.pendingEvents.concat($scope.completeEvents, $scope.missEvents, $scope.savedEvents);
                callback($scope.mainEvents);
            } else {
                $scope.datewise_event_data = [];
                $scope.mainEvents = [];
                $scope.eventInfoStatus = -1;
                $scope.setFlash('e', res.data.message);
            }
        })
    }
}

$scope.changeView = function (view, calendar) {
    console.log('chnageview');
    $timeout(function () {
        uiCalendarConfig.calendars[calendar].fullCalendar('changeView', view);
        $scope.eventsF;
    }, true);
};

$scope.renderCalender = function (calendar) {
    if (uiCalendarConfig.calendars[calendar]) {
        uiCalendarConfig.calendars[calendar].fullCalendar('render');
    }
};

$scope.calendarOptions = {
    height: 500,
    displayEventTime: false,
    themeSystem: 'standard',
   header: {
        left: '',
        center: '',
        right: 'prev,title,next'
    },
    buttonText: {
        month: 'Month',
        week: 'Week',
    },
    views: {
        agendaWeek: {
            titleFormat: "DD MMM",
            editable: true,
        },
        month: {
            titleFormat: "MMM YYYY",
            editable: false,
        }
    },
    eventDrop: function (event, delta, revertFunc, jsEvent, ui, view) {
        console.log(event);
        if (event.event_info.status == 0) {
            var start_date = event.start.toISOString();
            var end_date = event.end.toISOString();
            var obj = angular.copy({
                target_date: moment(start_date).format("YYYY-MM-DD"),
                target_intime: moment(start_date).format("HH:mm"),
                target_outtime: moment(end_date).format("HH:mm"),
                id: event.event_info.id
            })
            weekly_calenderService.change_calender_visit_datetime(obj).then(function (res) {
                if (res.data.flag) {

                } else {
                    revertFunc();
                    $scope.setFlash('e', res.data.message);
                }
            })
        } else {
            return false;
        }
        if (!confirm("Are you sure about this change?")) {
            revertFunc();
        }
    },
    eventClick: function (event) {
        if (event.view == 'month') {
            var obj = angular.copy({
                date: event.date,
                status: event.status
            })
            weekly_calenderService.get_calender_datewise_visits(obj).then(function (res) {
                if (res.data.flag) {
                    $scope.datewise_event_data = res.data.data;
                    $scope.eventInfoStatus = event.status;
                    console.log($scope.eventInfoStatus);
                } else {
                    $scope.datewise_event_data = [];
                    $scope.setFlash('e', res.data.message);
                }
            })
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    },
    eventRender: function (event, element, view) {
   //            console.log('test1');
   //            $compile(element)($scope);
    },
}

$scope.eventSources = [$scope.mainEvents, $scope.eventsF];
```

Comment: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/events-function

Comment: @ADyson for next and previous Button which one event used in angularjs1 https://angular-ui.github.io/ui-calendar/

Comment: Sorry I don't know what you mean. Can you be more specific about what you need? Why would you need to handle the next/previous button. If you implement the event feed using the function pattern - as per that link I provided - then the function will trigger automatically whenever the next/prev buttons are clicked. From there you can run whatever other code you need to fetch the events, and use the provided callback to pass the data back to fullCalendar asynchronously

Comment: Actually I want to call one function in all places like next,previous event and also changes on month and week view, I am using viewRender method but that's called 2 times same API.

Comment: Yes. the events function will run in all those cases. It happens automatically, triggered by fullCalendar.

Comment: @ADyson updated my questions, Please suggest me what's wrong when changing view from month to week $scope.getWeeklyDataFn(); function calling 3 times

Comment: I've already told you, you need to implement the events as a function pattern, as per the link I provided. Your update does not show any attempt to do that. Is there something you don't understand from that link and from what I explained?

Comment: @ADyson updated my questions, please check out, I want to call $scope.eventsF function when view changed like a month to week and week to a month.Is it possible?

Comment: I think I understand your request better now, thankyou. Why are you showing different events in month and week views? A view should just be a different perspective on the same set of events - that's how a calendar is intended to work. Let's say we are talking about last week (19th-25th July). It's not intended for a calendar to show different events just because you viewed that week within a "month" view, or within a "week" view, or within a "day" view. The calendar should show the same events - only the style of presentation would be different. What is the reason for your requirement?

Comment: @ADyson In month View I want to display a different layout and in week view I have a different layout so I want to call a different function. but now it's done I am using viewRender method and it's done.Thank you for your support.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to display week and month-wise different layouts or different events. In month-wise calendar only want to display Only event count and in week view also displaying information then this one may help you.

```
$scope.calendarOptions = {
    contentHeight: 'auto',
    displayEventTime: false,
    themeSystem: 'standard',
    defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
    lazyFetching: false,
    eventSources: [monthEvents, weekEvents],
    header: {
        left: '',
        center: '',
        right: 'month,agendaWeek,prev,title,next'
    },
    buttonText: {
        month: 'Month',
        week: 'Week',
    },
    views: {
        agendaWeek: {
            titleFormat: "DD MMM",
            editable: true,
            eventDurationEditable: false
        },
        month: {
            titleFormat: "MMM YYYY",
            editable: false,
            selectable: true
        }
    },
    viewRender: function (view) {
        $('#fullcalendar').fullCalendar('removeEventSource', monthEvents);
        $('#fullcalendar').fullCalendar('removeEventSource', weekEvents);
        $('#fullcalendar').fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
        $scope.datewise_event_data = [];
        monthEvents = [];
        weekEvents = [];
        var obj = angular.copy($scope.filter);
        var calendar = $('#fullcalendar').fullCalendar('getCalendar');
        var view = calendar.view;
        if (!view) {
            $scope.setFlash('e', "Something Wrong In getting Data.Please Refresh Again");
            return false;
        }
        obj.view_name = view.name;
        obj.start_date = moment(view.intervalStart._d).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
        obj.end_date = moment(view.intervalEnd._d).subtract(1, "days").format("YYYY-MM-DD");
        if (view.name == "agendaWeek") {
            $scope.completeEvents = [];
            weekEvents = [];
            weekly_calenderService.get_calender_week_wise_visits(obj).then(function (res) {
                if (res.data.flag) {
                    $scope.completeEvents = // Make Array here according to your need.
                    weekEvents = $scope.completeEvents;
                    $('#fullcalendar').fullCalendar('removeEventSource', monthEvents);
                    $('#fullcalendar').fullCalendar('addEventSource', weekEvents);
                    $('#fullcalendar').fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
                } else {
                    $scope.setFlash('e', res.data.message);
                }
            })
        } else {
            monthEvents = [];
            $scope.pendingEvents = [];
            weekly_calenderService.get_calender_month_wise_visits(obj).then(function (res) {
                if (res.data.flag) {
                    $scope.pendingEvents = // Make Array here according to your need.
                    monthEvents = $scope.pendingEvents;
                    $('#fullcalendar').fullCalendar('removeEventSource', weekEvents);
                    $('#fullcalendar').fullCalendar('addEventSource', monthEvents);
                    $('#fullcalendar').fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
                } else {
                    $('#fullcalendar').fullCalendar('removeEventSource');
                    $scope.setFlash('e', res.data.message);
                }
            })
        }
    },
    eventDrop: $scope.OnEventDrop,
    eventClick: $scope.OnEventClick,
    eventRender: function (event, element, view) {},
}
```

In Html

```
<div calendar="calendar" ui-calendar="calendarOptions" class="calendar" ng-model="eventSources" id="fullcalendar"></div>
```

I hope this one helps you.